# Service oir thread for Socket Connection

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, android-service

I need to make a socket connection to the server and maintain that connection until the app is closed. Should I create and maintain the connection in a service that my MainActivity can bind to or just create a new thread from the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to maintain the connection in service or thread because all network connection (connect/disconnect/request/response) should be call through service/thread otherwise ti will gives `ANR` error and gives warning that your task is run on main thread. So preferably  I will suggest you to start service and within service start thread. In that thread you have to do network connection. hope it helps you.